# How to ignore null refernce while exporting my grid data?

Tags: export-to-excel, openxml, nullreferenceexception, jqgrid-asp.net

I am loading a customer detail in a jqgrid table.
Using Open XML I am exporting my grid data. Here is the problem. One of my cell have null value in the database. Now while exporting I am getting Object Reference not set to an instance. How to ignore this issue?

Please help me out here. Have tried googling it but couldn't find any solution.

```
public string ExportReport(int cp, int noOfOrders)
{
    string conndb=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Db"];
    const string Ids ="0";
    Company pList = _items.GetByCID(cp);
    IQueryable<Product> List

    List=product.SQLDatabase().GetListByCompandIds(cp, Convert.ToInt32(noOfOrders), conndb, Ids)

    XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled);
    IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("ListReport");




        worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Customer Id";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "First Name";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "Last Name";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 4).Value = "Email";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 5).Value = "Department";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 6).Value = "Supervisor";


        int i = 2;
        foreach (EList ExpReport in List)
        {
            worksheet.Cell(i, 1).SetValue(ExpReport.CustomerId);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 2).SetValue(ExpReport.FirstName);  //*Here is where I am having error*
            worksheet.Cell(i, 3).SetValue(ExpReport.LastName);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 4).SetValue(ExpReport.Email);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 5).SetValue(ExpReport.Department);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 6).SetValue(ExpReport.Supervisor);
            ++i;
        }


        worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
        Session["Workbook"] = workbook;
        string filename;
        filename = "Product-Report";
        return filename;
}
```

Example:

```
For Example:

CustomerId      FirstName       LastName        Email        Department     Supervisor
123654          Adam            Ad              aa@abc.com   IT             Mike
456987                          Ferna           tf@abc.com   BA             Alferd
78931           Smith           Lopez           sl@abc.com   BA             Alfred
123456          John            Horvath         jh@abc.com   IT             Micheal
456789                          Cruise          cc@abc.com   BA             Alferd
78931           Jackson         Ville           JV@abc.com   BA             Alfred
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: @Kenney `worksheet.Cell(i, 2).SetValue(ExpReport.FirstName);`

Comment: Then I suppose you have to either skip `SetValue` when the argument is NULL, or set an empty string. How would you write that line of code so that it only executes when `ExpReport.FirstName` is not null?

Comment: @Kenney For ->How would you write that line of code so that it only executes when ExpReport.FirstName is not null?  -> I am expecting eventhough it is NULL in db it should export my data. If I skip SetValue then it won't export any names which actually have names in db, right?

Comment: No, it will only skip those names (cells, not rows) that are NULL.

Comment: I don't want to skip I also want that row to be added in the excel export. I have added an example in my description. What if I want to export that?

Comment: @Kenney Sorry,I misunderstood that. What do you mean to skip setvalue?How to skip it?

Comment: For example, `if ( ExpReport.FirstName != null ) worksheet.Cell(i, 2).SetValue(ExpReport.FirstName);`

Comment: @Kenney If I am doing `if ( ExpReport.FirstName != null ) worksheet.Cell(i, 2).SetValue(ExpReport.FirstName);` then whole column is blank in excel. Even though FirstName exist for specific customer

Comment: Then try adding an `else` and set an empty string (`""`).

Comment: @Kenney is there any universal solution so that if any of the columns besides FirstName column contains NULL value then it blank cell?

Comment: Not yet, but you can make one by making a function that takes a string (that may be null) and returns that string or an empty string if it is null, and wrap your fields in that function. So, define a function `filter` with the `if..else` in it, and then use `...SetValue( filter( ExpReport.... ) )`.

Comment: @Kenney Is this fine or might create any error in future?```worksheet.Cell(i, 1).Value = (ExpReport.CustomerId);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 2).Value = (ExpReport.FirstName);  
            worksheet.Cell(i, 3).Value = (ExpReport.LastName);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 4).Value = (ExpReport.Email);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 5).Value = (ExpReport.Department);
            worksheet.Cell(i, 6).Value = (ExpReport.Supervisor);```

Comment: ...@Kenney Was experimenting and found this. It does work but will there any scenario where this might not work? So do send me your view is this work all cases?